# Homotopy Groups of Connected Sums

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

This was sparked because I wanted to compute $\pi_2(Sym^2(\Sigma_2))$ via $Sym^2(\Sigma_2)\approx \mathbb{T}^4$# $\bar{\mathbb{C}P}^2$.
We know how to compute $\pi_1$ of $M$ # $N$ via van-Kampen's theorem. But what about higher homotopy groups? I looked in the literature and google without luck, and so I am wondering if no such procedure exists.  **Are there any results for calculating $\pi_n$ of connected sums?**

There was mention of "higher van Kampen theorem"... has this actually been used to do such computations? I'd be interested in references if not just examples.

Comment: Perhaps http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/higher+homotopy+van+Kampen+theorem ?

Comment: Higher homotopy groups, higher van Kampen theorems.

Comment: Sorry can this even be used in a connected-sum example? It seems just like "abstract theory".

Comment: I don't know of any examples of people using these higher homotopy van kampen theorems to compute anything new.   But if people can point out examples that would be great. 

Comment: "Abstract theory", hmm... are there non-abstract mathematics? Think of some elementary mathematics you think of as non-absrtract, pick an arbitrary individual in the street and ask him/her about his/her opinion...

Comment: In answer to Ryan Budney, one example in the joint paper Brown and Loday, Topology, 26 (1987), 311-334,  was the calculation of the 3-type of $X= S(K(G,1))$ in terms of the nonabelian tensor square $G \otimes G$, for any group $G$.  My bibliography on the nonabelian tensor product has 127 items (my name is on 7 of them), and [115] is on new calculations using  GAP. Group theorists are interested because the commutator map $G \times G \to G$ is a biderivation and so factors through a **morphism**  $\kappa:G \otimes G \to G$ whose kernel is $\pi_3 S(K(G,1))$. Abstract??!!

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The 2nd homotopy group of a connect sum is fairly reasonable to compute.  $\pi_i X$ is isomorphic to $\pi_i \tilde X$ provided $i \geq 2$ and $\tilde X$ indicates any covering space of $X$, so we might as well take the universal cover.  By the Hurewicz theorem, $\pi_2 \tilde X$ is isomorphic to $H_2 \tilde X$.  In the case of a connect sum, the universal cover has a very nice description (take disjoint unions of the universal covers of the punctured manifolds and glue them together appropriately).

Since $\mathbb CP^2$ is simply connected this is a fairly easy thing to compute.  The universal cover looks like $\mathbb R^4$ with a $\mathbb CP^2$ summand at every integer lattice point. So,

$$\pi_2 ((S^1)^4 \# \mathbb CP^2) \simeq \bigoplus_{\pi_1 T^4} \pi_2 \mathbb CP^2$$

i.e. a direct sum over $\mathbb Z^4$ of copies of the integers, i.e. $\mathbb Z[t_1^\pm, t_2^\pm, t_3^\pm, t_4^\pm]$ a laurent polynomial ring in four variables.  $\pi_1$ acts by multiplication by units in the Laurent polynomial ring.

Higher homotopy groups in general can be fairly painful to compute but $\pi_2$ is usually quite reasonable, like this case.

Comment: Ah perfect for $\pi_2$! Is there a deep reason why we can't do similar things for higher homotopy?

Comment: The anthropic principal response would be "homotopy groups are really useful, so if you could compute them easily, your life would become too easy". :) I don't have a deep reason to offer you, but if you take as an axiom that the homotopy groups of spheres are very complicated and there's mysterious patterns relating them, then since $S^n=\Sigma S^{n−1}$, there can't be a simple way to compute the homotopy groups of a CW-complex since that would force too obvious a symmetry into the homotopy-groups of spheres. Rational homotopy groups are much more manageable, but torsion is tricky.

Comment: The general framework I'm using starts running out of steam but it is usable.  $\pi_2$ we compute by going to the universal cover and computing $H_2$.  Okay, so what about $\pi_3$?  You'd kill $\pi_2$ via a fibration and compute $H_3$ of the total space of that fibration.  Basically we're using the Whitehead tower (as described in Hatcher's algtop book) where you kill the low-dimensional homotopy groups successsively.  If $\pi_2$ is free abelian you can kill it using a fibre bundle with fibre a product of circles (a generalized Hopf fibration). 

Comment: This is, in principle, the old Serre method for computing homotopy groups, isn't it? 

Comment: I thought Serre did a similar thing but usually the other way around, using a Postnikov system rather than the Whitehead tower. They're very similar ideas, though.  I would have known the answer when I was a grad student!

Answer (score 10):

Here is something that's valid in the stable range.

If $M$ and $N$ are closed $n$-manifolds, there is a cofibration sequence
$$
S^{n-1} \to M_0 \vee N_0 \to M\sharp N
$$
where $M_0$ denotes the effect of deleting a point from $M$.

If $M$ and $N$ are $r$-connected, then so is the connected sum. The Blakers-Massey excision theorem then implies an exact sequence
$$
\pi_k(S^{n-1}) \to \pi_k(M_0 \vee N_0) \to \pi_k(M\sharp N) \to \pi_{k-1}(S^{n-1}) \to \cdots
$$
as long as $k \le n-2+r$.

Furthermore the map $M_0 \vee N_0 \to M_0 \times N_0$ is $(2r+1)$-connected, so if 
$k \le 2r$ we get $\pi_k(M_0 \vee N_0) = \pi_k(M) \oplus \pi_k(N)$.

Assembling this, we have an exact sequence 
$$
\pi_k(S^{n-1}) \to \pi_k(M) \oplus \pi_k(N) \to \pi_k(M\sharp N) \to \pi_{k-1}(S^{n-1}) \to \cdots
$$
which is valid for $k \le 2r$, $r \le n-2$.

**Added Later**

I just realized one could simply note that the cofiber sequence gives a long exact sequence on stable homotopy
$$
\pi_k^{st}(S^{n-1}) \to \pi_k^{st}(M_0) \oplus \pi_k^{st}(N_0) \to \pi_k^{st}(M\sharp N) \to \pi_{k-1}^{st}(S^{n-1}) \to \cdots
$$
and then if $M$ and $N$ are $r$-connected with $k \le 2r$ and $r\le n-2$ we can use the Freudenthal suspension theorem to identify the stable groups with the corresponding unstable ones.  This gives a more elementary argument.

*Here's a special case:* when $M$ and $N$ are framed, so is $M\sharp N$ and the connecting map in the exact sequence splits to give a splitting
$$
 \pi_k(M\sharp N) = \pi_k(M) \oplus \pi_k(N) \oplus \pi_{k-1}(S^{n-1}) 
$$ 
(assuming the constraints on $k,r$ and $n$).

Comment: @ John Klein: The higher van Kampen theorems can sometimes give more information on $K \cup L$ when the intersection $K \cap L$ is not simply connected. For the connected sum we essentially have $P- K \cap L$ is a solid ball. What about other constructions, e.g.  $P= S^1 \times D^2$ ? or more complicated?  Are those of interest?

Comment: That should have been $P=K \cap L$. One example which worked well was when $P= K(G,1)$ for any group $G$ and $K,L$ are cones on $P$, so their union is the suspension of $P$.

Comment: What is the map $S^{n-1} \to M_0\vee N_0$? I'm having a hard time understanding this cofibration. I know of the cofibration $S^{n-1} \to M\#N \to M\vee N$, but not the one you're using here.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese The map in question is given as follows: let $S^{n-1} \to M_0$ and$S^{n-1} \to N_0$ be the attaching maps for the top cells of $M$ and $N$. Now form the composition $S^{n-1} \to S^{n-1} \vee S^{n-1} \to M_0 \vee N_0$, where the first map in the composite is the pinch map.

Answer (score 5):

Just a comment on the role of the Higher Homotopy Seifert-van Kampen Theorems:

they should be regarded as an extra tool in algebraic topology. There are quite severe conditions on their applicability but when they apply they compute quite a lot. Just as the 1-dimensional theorem, in its groupoid formulation, is about calculating 1-types, so the 2-dim theorem is about computing 2-types, in the form of crossed modules (over groupoids). However computing the second homotopy group from this 2-type may not be straightforward. But then the situation is the same for the 1-dim theorem, as is evidenced by the complications of theorems such as the Kurosh subgroup theorem, which can be seen to be  about the fundamental group(s) of a cover of a wedge of $K(G_i,1)$'s.

As a taster, based on the 2-d theorem, work with Chris Wensley enabled the computation of the crossed module representing the 2-type of the mapping cone of a map $Bf: BG \to BH$ induced by a morphism $f: G \to H$. Of course. the second homotopy group, even as a module over the fundamental group, is but a pale shadow of the 2-type. You can see some of this in our book (pdf available from my web page on the book).

R. Brown, P.J. Higgins, R. Sivera,  *Nonabelian algebraic
topology: filtered spaces, crossed complexes, cubical homotopy
groupoids*, EMS Tracts in Mathematics Vol. 15, 703 pages. (August
2011).

November 8, 2013: As a taster, let $X$ be the homotopy pushout  of the classifying spaces of the two maps of groups $P \to P/M, P \to P/N$ where $M,N$ are normal subgroups of the group $P$. The the homotopy 2-type of $X$ is determined by the crossed module $M \circ N \to P$, the coproduct of the two crossed $P$-modules, which is given by the pushout of crossed modules

$$\begin{matrix} (1 \to P) & \to & (N \to P) \cr
\downarrow && \downarrow \cr 
(M \to P)& \to  & (M \circ N \to P)
\end{matrix} $$. It follows that 
$$ \pi_2(X) \cong (M \cap N)/ [M,N]. $$
(Of course we know $\pi_1 X$ by the 1-dimensional van Kampen Theorem.) This result is applied in Bardakov, Valery G; Mikhailov, Roman; Vershinin, Vladimir V.; Wu, Jie, 
"Brunnian braids on surfaces". *Algebr. Geom. Topol.* 12 (2012), no. 3, 1607–1648.